# How to download a file with a sign in requirement either using Selenium or Postman

Tags: authentication, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I have a pretty irritating situation, that I have used 4 hours on. I need to download files with links and I need it to be scripted. The problem is that the links are protected by a sign in form.
[image]

I signed in and while checking the network tab and saw the following:

[image]

I then tried with the wrong password and I send the same request. Just receiving a 401.

I saw that I was not requested for authorization when I envoked the url again so I looked at the cookies and I could not see any stored password.
[image]

I checked the body of the page and it is `<html><head></head><body></body></html>` and the source tab is completely empty in all aspects of the process. So nothing there.

I then though okay lets try to make a Selenium automation.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
sleep(2)
print(driver.page_source)
driver.switch_to.alert()
```

And it opens the page and the sign in popup shows up. But it says there are no alert message:
selenium.common.exceptions.NoAlertPresentException: Message: no such alert

So to sum up_

- I can't find the way that the password is send over the network or any place that it is stored other than in the password manager in my browser
- I can't automate the sign in form since I can't find it
- I can access any information on the page source to see any javascript code.

Do you have any good ideas on what I have missed.

Comment: The auth will either be in a cookie or an authorization header (request header)

Comment: I have looked and pasted the request headers and the cookies

Comment: I can't tell what you're showing there but if you make a successful request you should be able to copy it as curl or fetch from network panel